# Equal height columns with Bootstrap 3 while preserving column padding

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, row-height

I have a regular Bootstrap 3 CSS setup. I want to apply the same heights to columns inside a row and have been looking at using `display:table` and `display:table-cell`. This method works but it naturally seems to apply vertical padding on the columns with less content.

Take this HTML for example:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <div class="block">
            Content for block<br />
            Some more content<br />
            And a bit more<br />
            Last bit
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-8">
        <div class="block">
            Content for block<br />
            Only some more content
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then this CSS:

```
.row { 
  display: table;
  width: 100%; }

.row > div {
  float: none;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top; }

.block { 
  height: 100%;
  background: red; }
```

Now the columns do have the same height, but the `.block`, which has the red background does not reflect this, because the second column has bottom padding applied which I cannot remove.

See this fiddle for an example: http://jsfiddle.net/cyan8fjz/

Is there a solution to get my `.block` to use the full `height:100%`? Ideally I do not want to absolutely position the `.block` because of the left and right padding on the columns (which may change at different screen resolutions).

Note I haven't included the Bootstrap CSS in my example above but I have in the fiddle. Assume it is relevant and included in all examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use like this ' `padding-bottom: 1000em; margin-bottom: -1000em;` trick.

Here's an example: **[Link](http://jsfiddle.net/jknntzsm/1/)**

Comment: Super! Allows me to apply further styles such as padding to the `.block` too without breaking anything. Thanks.